# How to divide 32 teams to 8 groups of 4 (similar to UEFA Champions League draw)?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 32 teams from various countries. Each country can be represented by up to 4 teams.

I need to divide those 32 teams into 8 groups - each consisting of 4 teams, no two teams can be from the same country within a group.

Is there a solution without the need to compute all the combinations after each pick to check whether the draw ends up in a dead end (e.g one spot left in a group but the last team can't go there because a team from the same country is already there)?

I was thinking I'd just use a simple algorithm to make the draw, check whether it meets the criteria, discard it if not and redo the draw. But there has to be a more elegant solution.

Thank you for your tips!